# SpriteKit leaves gap between nodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

When creating nodes - whether they're created from images or shapes - there's always a small gap between the nodes and the physics container, also between nodes in general.

I've already tried creating the nodes from shapes (rectangle, ball) and from an image and also stacking nodes.

```swift
let box = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        box.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300)
        box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: box.frame.size)
        box.fillColor = .red
        addChild(box)

let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 300)
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 15)
        ball.fillColor = .blue
        addChild(ball)

physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
```

Is there any way to leave no gap at all?

Comment: You need to add more info

Comment: Try to fill the .strokeColor also. It’s the border around the frame.